# How to add css style to android TextView string programmatically

Tags: android, css

> .glow {   font-size: 80px;   color: #fff;   text-align:
> center;   -webkit-animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;  
> -moz-animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;   animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; }
>
> @-webkit-keyframes glow {   from {
>     text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073;  
> }
>      to {
>     text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #ff4da6, 0 0 40px #ff4da6, 0 0 50px #ff4da6, 0 0 60px #ff4da6, 0 0 70px #ff4da6, 0 0 80px #ff4da6; 
> } }

Comment: you can use webview and load your text by html -- css

Comment: It is string passed from intent and set by setText,like   adText.setText(bundleIntent.getExtras().getString("text"));  can u explain me